# Why is mouseout fired when mousein is performed on a child element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

The definition of `mouseout` event [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) is as:

> The mouseout event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved off the element that has the listener attached or off one of its children.

So if I have a container div to whom `mouseout` is attached then I expect the event to be fired if the mouse moves out from any of its children. But what I am seeing is if mouse is moved in to container's child even then `mouseout` is being fired. Here is the example:

```js
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.over").mouseout(function(){
        $(".over span").text(x += 1);
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="over" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:left">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseout event triggered: <span></span></h3>
</div>
```

When the mouse is entered into the `h3` the `mouseout` on `div.over` is triggered. Why?

**Edit:** Please mention authoritative reference to back up your claim.

Comment: Because mouse pointer getting out from current element. Use mouseleave instead. It will triggered when pointer leave from releated element bounding box

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak No the mouse is not getting out from the current element. The `h3` is inside `div.outer`.

Comment: @user31782 :)  Imagine that you have a plate just front of your head. And some housefly landed on your shoulder. When it landed, you say there is a housefly on your body. Let's say that housefly jumped on that plate. You are not able to see that.  So, what you say about housefly ? It is still on you ?

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak if you mouse entered to `h3` element that means you are outside of div element ??

Comment: @Mahi In 2d projection "no". But think about z-order?. In my opinion, mouseout make sense, since there is only one pointer, when one element gets "mousein" then other one should say "mouseout"

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak but that's not MDN definition says

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak Sorry but I fail to understand how `h3` is outside of `div.over`. Both have same `z-index` here. `h3` is both _spatially_ and _logically_ inside `div.over`. For the moment lets assume `h3` is outside then why wouldn't `mouseleave` attached to `div.over` fire when mouse enters `h3`?

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak if you are in your home and you enter into your room . will that mean you are out of home ?

Comment: @Mahi :) browser window is the home in your metaphore actually.   take a look at this https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/mouse_over_out_versus_mouse

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak  maybe they have adopted this thing in their mind that if you go into room then you are out of home .

Comment: @mahi and Tolgahan That link is not any official source. Their idea is correct to make the definition validate by thinking in 3d. but even that 3d model doesn't fit to `mouseleave`. So this can't be a valid explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your div contains children, you "mouseout" of the container once you "mouseover" the children, this is by design. Since it is outside of its own visible space, and inside of its child's visible space. Since the child is also within the parent, it "inherits" the event, as it is treated as a separate volume, but still inside the space of the parent. This is why the event is triggered when you "mouseout" of the child. This is called "bubbling" the event bubbles up the family tree of elements.

As Mahi pointed out, if you use "mouseleave" it will only trigger once it leaves the area of the attached element.

The MDN documentation explain the difference here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave

But the authoritative answer is best viewed in the W3C DOM specification:

> it MUST be dispatched when the pointer device moves from an element onto the boundaries of one of its descendent elements.

So it clearly states that the event mouseout MUST be triggered when you move ONTO one of its child elements. So the reason for why this happens is by design, by specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseout

I have added a sample to show the difference

```js
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.over").mouseout(function(e){
        $(".over span").text(x += 1);
        console.log(e.target);
    });    
    $("div.over > h3").mouseover(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color", "red");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color","black");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="over" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:left">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseout event triggered: <span></span></h3>
</div>
```

```js
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.over").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".over span").text(x += 1);
    });    
    $("div.over > h3").mouseover(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color", "red");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color","black");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="over" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:left">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseout event triggered: <span></span></h3>
</div>
```

Now if you move the child element down in "z-space" it no longer effects the mouseout event:

```js
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.over").mouseout(function(){
        $(".over").css("background","red");
    }); 
    $("div.over").mouseover(function(){
        $(".over").css("background","#444");
    });       
    $("div.over > h3").css("display", "block");
    $("div.over > h3").css("position", "relative");
    $("div.over > h3").css("z-index", -1000);
    $("div.over > h3").mouseover(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color", "red");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".over > h3").css("color","black");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="over" style="background-color:lightgray;padding:20px;width:250px;float:left">
  <h3 style="background-color:white;">Mouseout event triggered: <span></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: _"...Since it is outside of it's own visible space"_. Along the same lines I can say _I "mouseleave" of the container once I "mouseover" the children._ But then why doesn't mouseleave get fired? The definitions of `mouseleave` and `mouseout` both use the word _off_. *Off* must have same meaning for both of them.

Comment: @user31782 so is this a question regarding the functionality of these events? Or about the wording in the web api documentation?

The mouseleave is relative to the entire area, ignoring any child element area, whereas the mouseout is relative only to the visible area.

Comment: @Espen It is about finding an appropriate reference which mentions the correct definition. _whereas the `mouseout` is relative only to the visible area_ This is what we speculate from the observed behavior of these events. My question is: Does JavaScript language documentations mentions this anywhere? Do we have an authoritative reference to back up this claim?

Comment: Also your javascript code in 3rd example is not correct. You are overiding `mouseout` upon `div.over` with `mouseover` when both happen. Your statement _Now if you move the child element down in "z-space" it no longer effects the mouseout event:_ is wrong. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Another js fiddle which is more explicit: https://jsfiddle.net/6ey8sh3v/1/ The counting changes when mounters child `h3` which has z-index negative 1000.

Comment: In your fiddle you ruin the z-index part by setting the container to be position relative. This fiddle shows that the event only happens when you go out of the parent element: https://jsfiddle.net/6ey8sh3v/3/ I feel that the MDN documentation explains exactly how this works. The mouseout and mouseover events bubble up the hiearchy of nested elements, triggering once per child, whereas the mouseleave and mouseenter does not. The documentation specifically show what use and when.

Comment: @user31782 I have updated my answer, with a link to what I feel is a definitive authoritative answer from the W3C spec

Answer (score 5):

The **mouseout** event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child elements as well the selected element.

The **mouseleave** event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves the selected element.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not asking about **`mouseleave`**. I am asking: When the mouse is entered into the child element(h3) the mouseout on parent(div.over) is triggered, why? The mouse is still inside the container div. The mouse doesn't go outside of any element yet.

Comment: best question i have seen . if you got answer please let me know too :) or else we will change the MDN definition .

Comment: If I get the answer then I will ping you in this post. By the way do you know any other authoritative reference than MDN for javascript?